# How to convert System.Reflection.PropertyInfo object to its original object type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Um looking for a way to convert a System.Reflection.PropertyInfo to its original object

```
 public static Child ConvertToChiildObject(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var p = (Child)propertyInfo;

    }
```

The propertyInfo object actulayy holds a class like this

```
public class Child{
  public string name = "S";
  public string age = "44";

}
```

So far I have tried implicit casting 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Are you want to get the value that your `propertyInfo` has? or else?

Comment: You would need to do `(Child)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj)` - but you *do* need an instance of the object with that property

Comment: @Irshad I have updated my question

Comment: @Rob I have updated my question , The required object is coming as a propertyInfo

Comment: You're misunderstanding how `PropertyInfo` works. It's describing a `Property`, but to read the value, you must also have an *instance*. For example, a `Parent` class might have a property `public Child child { get; set; }`. The `propertyInfo` would describe `Parent.child`, but *not* the value itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Child ConvertToChildObject(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object parent)
{
    var source = propertyInfo.GetValue(parent, null);
    var destination = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in destination.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
    {
       var value = source.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(source, null);
       prop.SetValue(destination, value, null);
    }

    return (Child) destination; 
}
```

In the above, I used the extra parameter `parent` which is the base object of the `Child`.

Comment: This code is not working at all " destination.GetProperties()" it should be destination.GetTyp().GetProperties()

Comment: I have fixed those , Thank you so much

Answer (score 16):

I must preface that this is not an answer to the question but an education excersise.

As others have explained you are misunderstanding the usage of the `PropertyInfo`  class. This class is used to **describe** the property and *does not* contain and instance related data. Therefore what you are trying to do is not possible without some additional information provided.

Now the `PropertyInfo` class *can* get the instance related data from an object but you must have an instance of the object to read the data from.

For example, take the following class structure.

```
public class Child
{
    public string name = "S";
    public string age = "44";
}

public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Child = new Child();
    }

    public Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

The property `Child` is a property of the `Parent` class. When the parent class is constructed a new `Child` instance is created as part of the `Parent` instance.

We can then use `Reflection` to get the value of the property `Child` by simply calling.

```
var parent = new Parent();
var childProp = typeof(Parent).GetProperty("Child");
var childValue = (Child)childProp.GetValue(parent);
```

This works just fine. The important part is `(Child)childProp.GetValue(parent)`. Note that we are accessing the `GetValue(object)` method of the `PropertyInfo` class to retrieve the value of the `Child` property from the **instance** of the `Parent` class.

This is fundementally how you would have to design the method for accessing the property data. However as we have listed a few times you **must** have an instance of the property. Now we can write an extension method that will faciliate this call. As I see it there is no advantage to use an extension method as the existing `PropertyInfo.GetValue(object)` method is quite quick to use. However if you would like to create a new instance of the parent object then get the value then you *could* write a very simply extension method.

```
public static TPropertyType ConvertToChildObject<TInstanceType, TPropertyType>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, TInstanceType instance)
    where TInstanceType : class, new()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = Activator.CreateInstance<TInstanceType>();

    //var p = (Child)propertyInfo;
    return (TPropertyType)propertyInfo.GetValue(instance);

}
```

Now this extension method simply accepts an instance as a second parameter (or first in the extension call).

```
var parent = new Parent();
parent.Child.age = "100";
var childValue = childProp.ConvertToChildObject<Parent, Child>(parent);
var childValueNull = childProp.ConvertToChildObject<Parent, Child>(null);
```

Results

```
childValue = name: S, age: 44
childValueNull = name: S, age: 100
```

Note the importance of having an instance.

*One Caveat*: The extension method will create a new instance of the object if the object is null by calling:

```
if (instance == null)
    instance = Activator.CreateInstance<TInstanceType>();
```

You will also notice the `typeparam` `TInstanceType` must be a `class` and must confirm to the `new()` restriction. This means it must be a `class` and must have a *parameterless* constructor.

I understand this isn't a solution to the question, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much , I really appreciate your answer and it helps me a lot!